# RelativeLayout vs OtherLayout can't get to line up

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am creating an APP that has several boxes based off some database data.  These boxes need to display specific information, of course, in a specific format.

Programatically, I have tried over the last couple days... `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `GridLayout`, and even `TableLayout` and can't get the proper results.

This is the layout I am trying to achieve....
[image]

Here is the basic portion of the code I have so far...

```
        // Create Main Box for spacing
        RelativeLayout acctrl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams acctrlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 225);
        acctrlp.setMargins(15, 5, 15, 5);
        acctrl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_account_box);
        acctrl.setId(R.id.rlAcctId);
        acctrl.setClickable(true);
        acctrl.setOnClickListener(acctclick);
        acctrl.setOnLongClickListener(acctlongclick);

        // Account New Ball & Count
        RelativeLayout rlNew = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlpNew = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        rlpNew.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        rlpNew.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        rlNew.setId(R.id.rlNewId);

        ImageView ivNew = new ImageView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ivpNew = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(168,168);
        ivpNew.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        ivpNew.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        ivNew.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.acct_msg_ball_blue);
        rlNew.addView(ivNew,ivpNew);

        TextView tvNewCount = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvpNewCount = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvpNewCount.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tvpNewCount.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        tvNewCount.setId(R.id.tvNewCountId);
        tvNewCount.setTextColor(COLOR.Black);
        tvNewCount.setPadding(0, -5, 0, 0);
        tvNewCount.setTextSize(25);
        tvNewCount.setText(String.valueOf(acct.get_new()));
        rlNew.addView(tvNewCount,tvpNewCount);

        TextView tvNewTitle = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvpNewTitle = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvpNewTitle.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        tvpNewTitle.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.tvNewCountId);
        tvNewTitle.setTextColor(COLOR.Black);
        tvNewTitle.setTextSize(10);
        tvNewTitle.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);
        tvNewTitle.setText("new");
        rlNew.addView(tvNewTitle,tvpNewTitle);
        acctrl.addView(rlNew);

        // Account Name
        TextView tvName = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvpName = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvpName.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        tvpName.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.rlNewId);
        tvpName.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,R.id.tvCountId);
        tvName.setId(R.id.tvNameId);
        tvName.setTextColor(COLOR.Black);
        tvName.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 5);
        tvName.setTextSize(25);
        tvName.setText(acct.get_name());
        tvName.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        tvName.setSingleLine();
        acctrl.addView(tvName, tvpName);

        // Account Position
        TextView tvPos = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvpPos = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tvpPos.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.rlNewId);
        tvpEmail.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        tvpPos.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,R.id.tvCountId);
        tvPos.setId(R.id.tvPosId);
        tvPos.setTextColor(COLOR.Black);
        tvEmail.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
        tvEmail.setTextSize(15);
        tvEmail.setText(acct.get_pos());
        tvEmail.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        tvEmail.setSingleLine();
        acctrl.addView(tvPos, tvpPos);
```

Not sure if this is the best way to go after all this.  It uses a `RelativeLayout` for the overall box.    It then uses another `RelativeLayout` to get the ball and the two different height `TextViews` centered in it on the left.   I haven't even started on the TOTAL JOBS section but that will probably need ANOTHER internal `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` to achieve the centering of the diff height `TextViews`.

Other than the confusing complexity, the current problems involve the ball...

1) I can't get the ball to center vertically in the box... no matter what I try.  This code puts it in the upper left corner.

2) I had to "fudge" the centering of the two different height `TextViews` within the ball using some negative padding based of of `CENTER_VERTICAL`.  Not sure if that is the best way to achieve it.

Any suggestions on how to fix what I have an ideally obtain these results would be greatly appreciated... I am pulling out my hair with this one.   Like I said, I tried a variety of different Layout commands, but it seems the farther I get into them, I am missing some key element with positioning,  centering or overlaying.

Thanks...

Comment: Why are you doing this in java and not xml? If you want I can give you the XML code to achieve the layout in picture.

Comment: I also think In xml is better. By the  way, your code seems to lack aligning or set position of rlNew etc. related to it's parent. Fill them with simple color to see what is happening.

Comment: I was doing this programmatically because it has to be called several times over for various accounts to display on one scroll-able page.   Thought that was the best way to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is xml code for required UI with image
**SampleActivity.java**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.RelativeSizeSpan;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sample_layout);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvinitial);
        String newName = "New";
        SpannableString ss1 = new SpannableString(newName);
        ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.6f), 0, newName.length(), 0); // set size
        ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, newName.length(), 0);
        textView.setText("");
        textView.append("15");
        textView.append("\n");
        textView.append(ss1);
    }
}
```

**Drawable XML**
**circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="35dp" />

            <solid android:color="#4cc9df" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#4cc9df" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**round_corner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**sample_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#e9e9e9"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_loc_arrow"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvinitial"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/new_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvinitial">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="ADAM JUNE"
                    android:textColor="#474747"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/second_txt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:text="Accountant"
                    android:textColor="#474747"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_layout">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TOTAL JOBS"
                    android:textColor="#3881a4"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="125"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#3881a4"
                    android:textSize="50sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/right_layout"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/arrow"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**ic_loc_arrow.png**

[ic_loc_arrow.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2RfU.png)

**Mobile ScreenShot**

[Mobile ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2k4x.png)

I hope this will resolve your issue.